# Usage of the word 用

Tags: meaning, difference

So I was watching a show and they say, 
你不用留爸爸

And I got confused as to why they used 用 in it.

Is it the same when you don't use 用 in that sentence? Like,

你不留爸爸

Comment: need to. have to

Comment: 用 means 需要 in this context

Comment: What is the context? Can you give us the sentence before and after? Could mean: Don't make Dad stay.

Answer (score 1):

你不用留爸爸 means "you don't need to/have to try to make dad stay"
你不留爸爸 would mean "you don't try to make dad stay", so more like stating a fact.